# Setting cookie in JSP and retrieving from non servlet class

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a situation where i need to set cookie in JSP and i need to get those cookie in normal java class.

The JSP:

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();

// create cookie
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", "John Doe");

// add cookie to CookieStore for a
// particular URL
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
url.openConnection().connect();
cookieJar.add(url.toURI(), cookie);
System.out.println("Added cookie using cookie handler");


%>
```

Below is the Java class [not a servlet class] and this class is running in the server and this is invoked not after the JSP call but somewhere in the application only if any event occurs. below is the code where i wrote to capture cookies.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.getContent();

CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);
cm.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieStore cs = cm.getCookieStore();
List <HttpCookie> cookies = cs.getCookies();
for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
          System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie);
}
```

would this scenario works if i want to retrieve the cookies in non servlet class?
The output of the above code will return empty list. 
However if i write a servet class with request.getCookie("UserName") I will see the cookie value.
Here i need to understand how would i get the cookie value without using request object. 
Because request object is not always passed in multiple invocation of java class. And i am not using session.
please let me know if you have any better approach.

Thanks-

Comment: Was there any reason to down vote the question. ? plz explain

Answer (score 0):

Instead Use the `getHeaderFields()` method from the connection Object to get the full list of Name-Value pairs representing the header fields of the specific connection

Cookie information(if present)should be under the “Set-Cookie” header field.

```
Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();
Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();
```

Then iterate over the `Set` and check if the cookie is present. If it is present print it out.

```
while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {
       String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();
       if ("Set-Cookie".equalsIgnoreCase(headerFieldKey)) {
       List<String> headerFieldValue = headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);
       for (String headerValue : headerFieldValue) {
       System.out.println("Cookie Found...");
       String[] fields = headerValue.split(";\s*");
       String cookieValue = fields[0];
       System.out.println("cookieValue:" + cookieValue);
            }
       }
   }
```

Y0u can refer this [examle](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/urlconnection/get-cookies-from-http-connection/)

Comment: From my question I found out that I am opening a URL connection which eventually a new connection object will not know about the cookie i set it in JSP.
In this case the cookies should send from browser to server after i set cookies in JSP.